# Subclass of integer64 staying after logical operation (R)

Tags: r, subclass, r-s3

When I subclass the integer64 object from bit64 and then perform a equality test, the result contains logical data, but is still classed with my class rather than being logical.  This doesn't happen with integer for example.

Sample code:

```
library(bit64)
x = as.integer64(5)
class(x) = c("Foo", "integer64")
x == 5
```

returns

```
[1] TRUE
attr(,"class")
[1] "Foo"
```

Notice that it still has class "Foo"

While if we do the same with integer:

```
y = as.integer(5)
class(y) = c("Foo", "integer")
y == 5
```

It returns logical

```
[1] TRUE
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the implementation of equals for `integer64` variables.

```
`==.integer64`
function (e1, e2) 
{
    a <- binattr(e1, e2)
    e1 <- as.integer64(e1)
    e2 <- as.integer64(e2)
    ret <- logical(max(length(e1), length(e2)))
    .Call("EQ_integer64", e1, e2, ret)
    a$class <- minusclass(a$class, "integer64")
    setattributes(ret, a)
    ret
}
```

The return value is explicitly given a class attribute equal to the class of `a`, minus the class `"integer64"`.

`binattr`, that creates the variable `a` is a rather odd function that checks that the two inputs are of a compatible size, then returns the attributes of one or the other, depending upon which ones have a `dim` attribute.

Comment: Good spot - any idea why they would do that?

Comment: Wildly guessing: I think that the main concern is to copy the `dim` attribute to the result, so matrix inputs aren't flattened.  Copying the class should preserve any special methods, e.g., printing.